# How to create and expose ui commands by XSP.executeCommand() in Xpages (IBM 9 Xpinc)?

Tags: xpages

I am trying to create and expose UI command in XPages(xpinc) IBM 9 but unsure of where to start.

There is new feature is avialable in IBM 9 to connect ClientSide JavaScript to Java classes 
using **XSP.executeCommand()** from client side

seems we can expose UI commands using this concept such as Update the Notes status bar with 
a user message, add an icon to the Notes workspace, etc

The concept is descriped in IBM 9 feature presenation. Refer the below link(page No 37 & 38)
(http://www.tlcc.com/admin/tlccsite.nsf/files/Whats_New_11-14-2012-sm.pdf/$FILE/Whats_New_11-14-2012-sm.pdf)

Can anyone show me easy way to create a sample?

Where do i have to write my java code and how do I  link from client side?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to source some sample code.

But basically your Eclipse plugin needs the following:

```
Extension point: com.ibm.xsp.rcp.ExtendedCommands
Implements:      IExtendedCommands
```

Then you should be able to call it with the XSP.ExecuteCommand() method.

For examples on the NotesUIWorkspace API you can check out the [Java UI API Exerciser](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/release.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=9962EFCE130305FC862576A9005890C3) on OpenNTF.

Comment: Do i need to create new Plugin project to achieve this? Can you add example here? advice me how i need to proceed.

Comment: For your own custom plugins, yes you would. For NotesUIWorkspace the link should contain examples and shouldn't require the creation of a plugin.