# XSP.executeCommand examples?

Tags: xpages

A previous question asked about XSP.executeCommand that is now available in Domino 9.0.1. A responder, Simon, said that access to the NotesUIWorkspace class is available without having to create a plugin.

[How to create and expose ui commands by XSP.executeCommand() in Xpages (IBM 9 Xpinc)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920591/how-to-create-and-expose-ui-commands-by-xsp-executecommand-in-xpages-ibm-9-xp)

How is the Extension point `com.ibm.xsp.rcp.ExtendedCommands` used.

Comment: This is on topic for XPages. Why would it get marked as off-topic?

Comment: Robert, please take the question off topic. I've edited the question accordingly. As a subject matter expert, I can confirm the in-application help does not provide adequate information. I can also confirm the quoted question does not supply enough information for even an experienced XPages developer to implement a solution. There is a correct answer which is not an opinionated answer or spam, which I would like to add.

Comment: @PaulStephenWithers looks like this is open again now.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one source for how to use XSP.executeCommand, Mastering XPages Second Edition, Chapter 13, pp 624 - 632, the section called "Extended Client-Side JavaScript Commands"